# How to specify tail value of a Poisson distribution in scipy.stats?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I want to create a Poisson distribution with mean is 2 number of elements is 10000 has min value 1 and tail value 140 so far I can only specify the min

```
 stats.poisson.rvs( 2, loc = 1,size=10000)
```

and the following distribution is generated [image]

How can I make it end at 140 instead of 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chance that a sample out of a Poisson distribution with mean equal to 2 is greater than 140 is so small that you would not get one out of just 10000 samples.

Indeed, the Poisson distribution has only one parameter λ and  a probability mass function defined so that

```
P(x=k) = λ^k * exp(-λ) / k!
```

The mean value is also equal to λ. If λ = 2 then

```
P(x=140) = 7.7e-199
```

so if there are 10000 samples the chance that there would be at least one sample
at 140 out of 10000 would be less than 7.7e-195. This is a number so small that you cannot expect this to occur in a lifetime.

It is a bit harder to compute the probability that a sample out of Poisson distribution with λ=2 lies above 140. You can use `scipy.stats.poisson.cdf` to see that

```
P(x>=22) = 1 - scipy.stats.poisson.cdf(21,2) = 5.5e-16
```

Therefore even the chance that you would have one sample out of 10000 above 21 is less than 5.5e-12. Computing `P(x>=140)` in the same way would return 0 because of floating point rounding in intermediate results.

**Conclusion**

If you want distribution mean equal 2.0, and a heavy tail reaching up to 140 on 10000 samples you need a distribution different from Poisson. You could consider Pareto distribution, `scipy.stats.pareto` with parameter b = 2.

Here is a comparison of 10000 random samples from

```
scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(2,size=10000)
```

and

```
numpy.rint(scipy.stats.pareto.rvs(2,size=10000))
```

[image: Comparison of Poisson and Pareto distributions]

It is clearly visible that Pareto distribution with the same mean has a much heavier tail.

For reference the code for the plot is below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np
pareto_x = np.rint(scipy.stats.pareto.rvs(2,size=10000))
poisson_x = scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(2,size=10000)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.title("Poisson distribution, a = 2")
plt.xlabel("sample number")
plt.ylabel("sample value")
plt.axis([0,10000,0,180])
plt.plot(range(0,10000),poisson_x,"o")
plt.subplot(122)
plt.axis([0,10000,0,180])
plt.title("Pareto distribution, b = 2")
plt.xlabel("sample number")
plt.plot(range(0,10000),pareto_x,"o")
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4,bottom=0.2)
plt.savefig("poisson_pareto.png")
```

Comment: This is very helpful can you please post the the code you used to create this graph

Comment: Perhaps worth stating the obvious: a Poisson distribution does not have a maximum value.  As you say, the question is just how low a probability you're willing to consider "low enough" to define a "maximum" such that all higher values have "low enough" probability.